# JQuery/AJAX Unable to Get Response from PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to run a server side python script for my wordpress site. I can call the python file inside a php function and run it on the site as shortcode. So, the php file is working. The issue I am having is building my JQuery and getting the response from the php file. I am trying to do a hello_world set-up to debug the issue

AJAX Query:

```
function myFunction() {
  alert("Testing button");
}

function HelloWorldShortcode() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      method: 'POST',
      url: "http://localhost/wp-content/helloworld.php",
      data: {
        action: 'helloworld'
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert("bad");
      },
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    });

  })
}
```

and the php file:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function hello_world() {
    $test = 'hello';
    return $test;
}

if (isset($_POST['helloworld'])) {
    return hello_world();
}
```

I have also tried using GET instead of POST. When I access the php file in the browser I do not get any errors and the `success` part of the ajax query is being reached, as i do not get any error messages. What can I do to access the `hello_world()` function inside of the php file and display the output?

Thanks

Comment: Don't think a return is the correct way to respond to an Ajax call. Try an `echo hello_world();`

Comment: in your code, `data: { action: 'helloworld' }` its `action` php should be looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the value of the parameter, not the parameter itself...

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    echo hello_world();
    // Or json_encode(hello_world()); for returning an Array 
}
```

or

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'helloworld') {
    return hello_world();
    // Or json_encode(hello_world()); for returning an Array 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['helloworld'])) {
    echo hello_world();
    // Or json_encode(hello_world()); for returning an Array 
}
```